# Blazorhosted ASP.NET Core 3 as Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

Should hosting a Blazor netcore 3.0 ASP.NET app through Azure App Services be working? I just set up the sample app using preview3 blazorhosted template which works fine locally, but it's not working as an Azure app service. Has anyone tried this on the new core3 templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, you need to install .NET Core 3.0 on your web app in Azure, check extensions, install preview and restart the app.

Comment: Thanks! I had to pick the x86-version to get it working. I find the whole Blazor hosting models a bit confusing, but I assume they'll clear it up in the future.

Comment: You are welcome.
Yes, sorry I forgot to mention about x86.
Good luck with blazor :)